# How can two users share their screen to each other simultaneously?

Tags: video-streaming, screen-sharing

I haven't been able to find a screen sharing software where multiple users can share their screen (specifically, an application window)  simultaneously while being able to see the other users' shared screens.

It only needs to support two users: user 1 sharing his screen to user 2, and user 2 sharing his screen to user 1.

For example, I tested Zoom, but while Zoom allows sharing multiple screens simultaneously, those users who share their screen can't see the shared screens of the other users (because the Zoom window hides itself while sharing one's screen). If user 1 and user 2 both share their screens, only other users in the meeting (user 3, 4 etc.) can see both screens.
https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115000424286-Sharing-multiple-screens-simultaneously

Other screen sharing software solutions that I've found do not advertise this feature. I haven't been able to find any article about this use case either.

I guess I should mention that there is one solution we've found: use two different screen sharing applications simultaneously. For example, user 1 uses Teams to share his screen to user 2, and user 2 uses Zoom to share his screen to user 1. Very cumbersome and performance hungry, though.

Comment: So User 1 sees the screen of User 2 and User 2 sees screen of User 1... which is displaying screen of User 2? How do you imagine this would work?

Comment: Screen sharing software usually allows sharing only one application window. So for example, I share my text editor to the other user, and I have a screen sharing window open where I see the text editor of the other user.

Comment: Reopened for you.

Comment: And if each user has two monitors, user 1 can share his monitor A to user 2, and see user 2's screen-sharing window on his monitor B.

@DavidPostill: thank you!

Comment: You can create infinite loops of sharing and sharing and exponentially create lag. How would you prevent the screen from being shared that is already shared and is shared again and then is also still being shared?

Comment: @Nelson: by restricting sharing to one application window.

Comment: Surprised to see the confusion about this. Seems like a common requirement for two people to be able to see each other's screens while they work. Consider training a new employee. User A does something in their application and user B must repeat that while user A watches.

Answer (score 0):

Google Meet supports this. Not sure when it was added, so it may be part of the "new experience" currently being rolled out in June 2021.

You may want to turn off both cameras to improve performance, since you will likely be paying attention to the screens anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Tuple" is an app on macos for two-way screen sharing and pair programming.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this problem. You can use this website https://webcall.replit.app
. Completely secure , no sign in required , and instant screen sharing.  And you and your freind can share his screen at same time.  I personally use it regularly for coding with my freind.

Comment: First, the link is bad.  Second, is it your site ?

Comment: Why is the link bad? Yes this is my site